# Should I delete an answer that I no longer agree with?

Tags: discussion

I find that every now and then I get a little rep from an answer that's old enough that I've really changed my mind about the issue since then. I always feel guilty when this happens, and feel like I should delete my answer. Should I leave my answer or delete it? (It's not strictly speaking wrong or anything, I just have a different way of approaching the issue now, and would not answer the question the same way if I answered it today.)

As for editing it instead of deleting it, is it ok that I would change the meaning of the answer, where it would have gotten some +1s for a meaning that it no longer has?

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Editing it is probably better than deleting it.

Comment: Up to you is the answer. There is not just Black or White it always depend of the situation.

Comment: If its not wrong I wouldn't delete it, editing does seem like the way forward

Comment: `"is it ok that I would change the meaning of the answer"` - If you're concerned about this, consider including both ways of doing it (if applicable, and assuming the original is actually right), but do try to stay away from something like "EDIT: I now think this is a better way...", rather rewrite the answer, as if writing it from scratch with both approaches (you'd probably put the preferred way at the top).

Comment: @Dukeling That would make part of a good answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you think that the world would be a better place with that answer publicly available, or do you think that the world would be better off if it didn't exist.  If you think the latter, then delete the answer.

If you want to edit it, that's just fine.  There are concerns about editing a question to radically change what it's asking, especially if it will invalidate answers, but for an answer there really is no such rule/guideline.  If you want rewrite the answer from scratch to use what you feel is a better approach, that's entirely fine.  The old answer is still there in the revision history if people want to see it.

Answer (score 3):

If your answer has no upvotes, feel free to delete it.

However, if it has some upvotes, it means that it was useful for someone. By removing it, you will remove the content that was valuable to someone. You should do it only for serious reasons, such as an error in the answer that can't be fixed by editing.

Change of mind when it comes to 'good' or 'bad' practices shouldn't matter. Practices are opinion based. That what matters on SO is the solution that functions, is easy to understand and as short as possible.